# Need help targeting a nested json object SwiftUI *Question clarified*

Tags: json, swiftui

Im currently hitting a wall as I'm trying to display information from an array within a nested json object. I can't understand where I am going wrong, so any help will be greatly appreciated. **The current error I am receiving is : *Fatal error: Index out of range*

I believe my problem may be in regards to how I am targeting the information. I have outlined using "!! ... !!" the key areas where I believe the error is being made.

I am confused because of how the json object is nested. If I'm correct, the heiarchy for my desired target is: object(main object) -> object(DATA) -> array(newReleases) -> String(prId). With that being said Im under the impression my **self.posts = results.data.newReleases** would then be targeting the newReleases array directly(which I want), for it to then be printed in the contentView *Text(networkManager.posts[0].prID)*

Content View where the list is declared:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var networkManager = NetworkManager()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
                
            List{
                Text(networkManager.posts[0].prID)
            }
                
                .navigationTitle("Json Test")
            }
        .onAppear{
            self.networkManager.fetchData()
        }
    }
}
```

Heres a photo of the JSON Data formatted.

[JSON Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXoD8.png)

This is how I have the data defined in my app:

```
// MARK: - Results
struct Results: Codable {
    let data: DATAClass

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case data = "DATA"
    }
}

// MARK: - DATAClass
struct DATAClass: Codable {
    let newReleases, exclusives, preorders, backIssues: [BackIssue]
}

// MARK: - BackIssue
struct BackIssue: Codable {
    let totalcount: String
    let sectionName: SectionName
    let sectionLink, prID, prParentid, prTtle: String
    let prPrice, prLprice, prSimg, prBimg: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case totalcount
        case sectionName = "section_name"
        case prID = "pr_id"
        case prTtle = "pr_ttle"
        case prPrice = "pr_price"
        
    }
}


}

enum SectionName: String, Codable {
    case featuredNewReleases = "FEATURED_NEW_RELEASES"
    case recommendedBackIssues = "RECOMMENDED_BACK_ISSUES"
    case recommendedPreOrders = "RECOMMENDED_PRE_ORDERS"
}
```

Heres where I am attempting to decode the json object:

```
@Published var posts = !! [BackIssue]() !!
    
    func fetchData() {
        if let url = URL(string:" https://www.midtowncomics.com/wcfmt/services/product.svc/load-featured-sections?apiKey=&mtUser=&mtPass=&sh_id=76367&pgn=home&app_id") {
            let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
            let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
                 if error == nil {
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    if let safeData = data {
                        do {
                          let results = try decoder.decode(Results.self, from: safeData)
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                !! self.posts = results.data.newReleases !! 
                            }
                            
                            
                        } catch {
                            print(error)
                        }
                       
                    }
                    
                }
            }
            task.resume()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't shown where you're trying to decode the data or if there's an error that you're encountering when doing say. Can you clarify what the issue is that you're having?

Comment: Im so sorry. I completed forgot to add it. I have now updated where I am attempting to decode the information.

Comment: You still haven't said if you're encountering an error or what the expected result vs. what you're experiencing.

Comment: @jnpdx Hey sorry about that. I have updated the post and clarified my question. Im running into a error: Fatal error: Index out of range when trying to display the data in the content view.. That is essentially all Im trying to do currently; correctly target the data and have it displayed. So I'm not sure if its my approach that is off, or the way I'm targeting the data.

Answer (score 0):

Never get an item by hard-coded index in the rendering area of an SwiftUI view. If the array is empty the code crashes reliably.

Get the item safely by replacing

```
Text(networkManager.posts[0].prID)
```

with

```
Text(networkManager.posts.first?.prID ?? "n/a")
```

Better is a `ForEach` loop which is skipped if the array is empty.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. So if I'm seeing "n/a" as the returned value, am I correct to assume that means I'm not even targeting the information?

Comment: Basically yes. The crash occurs because the array is (still) empty when the view is rendered the first time as you fetch the data asynchronously. Use a `ForEach` loop which won't crash.

Comment: shouldn't this suffice? " List(networkManager.posts) { post in
                HStack{
                    Text(post.prID)
                }
            }". ...Its not running for me. But I don't understand why. Is my problem in regards to how I targeting the data? Or bc of how I am trying to display it?... essentially all I am trying to do is be able to access the data within the level of the Json object, so that I can eventually display the object as an item within a view.

Comment: `List` and `ForEach` do the same in this case. In SwiftUI it's highly recommended to put the asynchronous stuff into an `@ObservableObject`. And be aware that for an `@ObservedObject` **you** are responsible for the life cycle.

Comment: Im confused tho, isn't that how I have it set up? I apologize if I am misunderstanding what you are explaining. Im just having a hard time understanding where my mistake is. Is there any possible way you can provide me an example in which a single prID data is displayed on the content view? If I can just see how it should look, ill be able to see where I'm going wrong.